# Libpng fix for gamemaker

Tags: libpng, game-maker, game-maker-studio-1.4

I'm using gamemaker, and I received a warning saying that I am using an old version of libpng and I don't know what does it mean, and how do I fix it.
First off what is libpng?

Comment: Not a useful question - missing tags, code and background info. Bad first attempt at a question. Please read site guidelines

Answer (score 2):

This is due to Gamemaker not having updated to latest version of libpng. Read more here: http://bugs.yoyogames.com/view.php?id=21962

Answer (score 0):

libpnj is a library used by gamemaker to deal with images :
http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/libpng.html

You can update it here : https://sourceforge.net/projects/libpng/